# How to read floats and Strings in python?

Tags: python, string, double

I have the following input:

`-122.02060305 37.28598884 1427 Alderbrook Ln San Jose 95129`

The input is in format Longitude Latitude Destination

In order, they are `float` `float` `String`

I want to set the variable `currentLong` to the first float, and the variable `currentLat` to the second float, and the variable `desiredDestination` to the rest of the input, which is the address, so basically "1427 Alderbrook...95129"

I've done java mostly, and am mostly new to python.

I am not running this on the command line. I am using this in a flask project.

Answer (score 4):

`str.split()` takes a optional second argument which determines how many times to split. For your case you can send in 2 as the second argument and `None` as the first, so that it splits the string with any whitespace upto 2 times. Code -

```
s = "<your string>"
currentLong, currentLat, desiredDestination = s.split(None,2)
```

Then if you need currentLong and currentLat as floats, you would need to convert them into float using `float()` , Example -

```
currentLong, currentLat = float(currentLong), float(currentLat)
```

Example -

```
>>> s = "-122.02060305 37.28598884 1427 Alderbrook Ln San Jose 95129"
>>> s.split(None,2)
['-122.02060305', '37.28598884', '1427 Alderbrook Ln San Jose 95129']
```

Comment: The second argument is called [`maxsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: @AnandSKumar it is giving me an error when I call:

`s = myInput`
`longitude, latitude, destination = s.split(None,2)`

And what exactly is maxsplit @BhargavRao

Comment: @AnandSKumar `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: obviously myInput is None, check y?

Answer (score 1):

You may do splitting and assigning the parts to three separate variables.

```
stri = "-122.02060305 37.28598884 1427 Alderbrook Ln San Jose 95129"
s = stri.split()
currentLong, second float, desiredDestination = s[0],s[1],s[2:]
```

Comment: I need the currentLong and currentLat to be floats while desiredDestination to be a String and what does the code `s[0],s[1],s[2:]` mean?